# URL Target Link Tab - Zurb Foundation Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am currently using [Zurb Foundation Tabs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html) for small project. The tabs work great but I am running into a wall when trying to url target to an specific tab. I searched and found a method for getting this achived but when modifying and applying it to my example it is not working. I am getting error: “unrecognized expression: :nth-child”. How can I properly url link to a specific tab in Foundation 5? [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/tabs_test/index.html)

JS/JQuery for url target

```
<script>
window.navigateTab = function (event) {
    var url = $(event.target).attr('href');
    var target = url.split('#')[1];
    if (target.substr(0, 5) == 'panel') {
      var state = {
          tab: target.substr(5)
      };
      selectTab("tabs_edit", state.tab); //<-- change the tab
      history.pushState(state, null, url); //<-- change the url
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    }

    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
      if (event.state != null) {
          selectTab("tabs_edit", event.state.tab); //<-- change the tab
      }
    };

    function selectTab(id, tab) {
      // activate only the right tab:
      var tab = $("#" + id + "> dl > dd:nth-child(" + tab + ")");
      console.log(tab);
      var a = $("a", tab);
      target = $('#' + a.attr("href").split('#')[1]);
      siblings = tab.siblings();
      settings = tab.closest('[data-tab]').data('tab-init');

      tab.addClass(settings.active_class);
      siblings.removeClass(settings.active_class);
      target.siblings().removeClass(settings.active_class).end().addClass(settings.active_class);
    }

    $('#menu a').on("click", navigateTab);
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

HTML

```
      //Target an specific tab:
       <ul id="menu" class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#panel1a">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel2a">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#panel3a">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        //Actual Tabs
            <dl id="tabs_edit" class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
              <dd class="active"><a  href="#panel1a" onclick="navigateTab(event)">Tab 1</a></dd>
              <dd><a href="#panel2a" href="#panel2a" onclick="navigateTab(event)">Tab 2</a></dd>
              <dd><a href="#panel3a" href="#panel3a" onclick="navigateTab(event)">Tab 3</a></dd>
              <dd><a href="#panel4a" href="#panel4a" onclick="navigateTab(event)">Tab 4</a></dd>
            </dl>
            <div class="tabs-content vertical">
              <div class="content active" id="panel1a">
                <p>Panel 1 content goes here.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="content" id="panel2a">
                <p>Panel 2 content goes here.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="content" id="panel3a">
                <p>Panel 3 content goes here.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="content" id="panel4a">
                <p>Panel 4 content goes here.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old but after reading more into the foundation 5 text they've added Deeplinking features that works on different pages

Just add this :

data-options="deep_linking:true"

Example:

```
<dl class="tabs vertical" data-tab data-options="deep_linking:true">
```

This even works on different pages linking to it!

For link on other pages I just called the panelid

Example:

```
<a href="product-line.php#panel12">
```

Answer (score 1):

Deep linking is something that Foundation 5 has not included as found in Foundation 4. I have made a fix that is not as clever but gets the job done:

```
  if(window.location.hash){
                $('dl.tabs dd a').each(function(){
                    var hash = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
                    if(hash == window.location.hash){
                        $(this).click();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Extend perhaps to `$('dl.tabs dd a').add($('ul.tabs li a')).add($('ol.tabs li a'))`